# rename file using php

Tags: php, format, rename, wav

I would like to change the extension and add a character to the end of a filename in the "Albums/testgallery" directory, but I want the code to work with all galleries.

I would like to rename all files uploaded, example: "sound.wav" to "sound1.mp3"

Yes I know this does not change the format.

I have tried a few options, but nothing happens.

Any advise?

Comment: paste your code. So we know where you might have missed it

Comment: code pls? so that we can debug it

Comment: I tried $filename = preg_replace('"\.wav$"', '.mp3', $filename); I want all files that are added to different directories with the wav extension to be renamed to mp3

Answer (score 0):

Since, you did not paste any code, i will assume you have this:

TO rename the file, use php's rename function.

```
<?php
rename("path_to_where_you_stored_the_old_file", "new_name_of_the_file");
?>
```

In your case, you can try:

```
<?php
    rename("path_where_you_saved_sound.wav", "sound1.mp3");
    ?>
```

Comment: I tried $filename = preg_replace('"\.wav$"', '.mp3', $filename); I want all files that are added to different directories with the wav extension to be renamed to mp3